# Overriding Backbone.sync

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I'm trying to override Backbone.sync in order to set the "id" attribute every time we fetch a model. This way, I am sure the next model.save() will fire an *update* and not a *create*, even if the fetch() didn't respond with an id.

```
Backbone._sync = Backbone.sync;
Backbone.sync = function(method, model, options) {
    var params = _.clone(options);
    params.success = function(model) {
        if(method == 'read' && model.isNew()) {
            var id = Math.floor(Math.random()*1000);
            model.set({ "id": id });
        }
        if(options.success) options.success(model);
    };
    Backbone._sync(method, model, params);
}
```

But the model passed to the success function seems not to be a Backbone model, but just an object. So I can't use any method (like model.isNew()) on it. Any idea of what I did wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It sounds like you might want to override `Model.fetch` or `Model.parse` instead of `Backbone.sync`. `Backbone.sync` just takes `$.ajax()` options, so the `success` callback is just receiving the JSON response from the server, not an instantiated model.

The default `Model.fetch()` callback looks like this:

```
options.success = function(resp, status, xhr) {
    if (!model.set(model.parse(resp, xhr), options)) return false;
    if (success) success(model, resp);
};
```

Here `model` refers to the current instance, as you intend. So you might consider overriding `Model.fetch` to add an id if it's not there, or, probably better, overriding `model.parse()`, which is a passthrough by default and is intended as a hook for you to munge the server data. I'm not thrilled with your random number id implementation, as there's still a chance of collisions, especially if you're making a lot of models - you might try using `model.cid` (guaranteed to be unique in the client, though it might have collisions with server-provided IDs) or Underscore's [_.uniqueId()](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/#uniqueId):

```
parse: function(resp, xhr) {
    if (this.isNew() && !resp.id) {
        resp.id = _.uniqueId('model-');
    }
}
```

Comment: Agreed.  `Backbone.sync` is more about your transport/protocol.  You override it to handle map the "create", "update", etc verbs to your technology.  By default, `Backbone.sync` is HTTP/REST but you can change it out if you want something else (like Socket.io or local storage).  If you want to do something with the data (like set the ID), it should happen in the model like you are suggesting.

Comment: @BrianGenisio Can you please tell me how to use both parse and fetch's success callback? I want to use parse to isolate meta data and then my rendering logic in success. But if i define model.parse the success callback never gets called.

Comment: @BlackDivine Are you also overriding `set` but not returning anything?  Or are you getting an exception some place?  If you look at the source code for `fetch` I don't see any other way. http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/docs/backbone.html#section-40

Comment: Thanks @BrianGenisio, I found bug. I had binded view to model.change and that messed things up :)

Answer (score 1):

@nrabinowitz

Just to add tiny more amount of clarity to this.  I am using RedbeanPHP which has inbuilt JSON support.  One issue is that when you create an object, it returns the new id of that object in the result tag, and you need this for the new object if you want to edit it.

```
   // My model object is a User. (we are all Users in some way).
   var User = Backbone.Model.extend(
            {   
                url : "/user/rpc",
                defaults: {
                    email: "email",
                    password: "",
                    admin: 0
                },parse: function(resp, xhr) {
                               // check if the model is new, if so, set the id of this model for future requests so RedBean knows the id of this object.
                   if(this.new()){
                    this.set({"id":resp.result});
                    console.log(this);
                             }
               }

            }   
        );
```

Comment: I don't see what you're doing here. Actually my problem was more a design problem, since the best way, I think, is to generate an id server-side and to return it. Then Backbone automatically sets the id to the model. Why would you set the entire result as an id? And what is the model.new() syntax you are using?